# docker network create, what is the difference between --subnet and --ip-range

Tags: docker, docker-network

The Docker Networking documentation states:

- subnet :  Subnet in CIDR format that represents a network segment
- ip-range : Allocate container ip from a sub-range

And the example shows:

```sh
$ docker network create \
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=172.28.0.0/16 \
  --ip-range=172.28.5.0/24 \
  --gateway=172.28.5.254 \
  br0
```

So, the subnet is from 172.28.0.0 to 172.28.255.255

And the ip-range is from 172.28.5.0 to 172.28.5.255

Why would you make the subnet larger than the ip-range?

Why is there a subnet AND an ip-range option?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking at macvlan networks might give a better use case than the bridge networks. macvlan networks create MACVLAN type slave network interfaces virtually attached to a host (hardware) network interface, the master. MACVLANs are like multiple network interfaces with separate MAC addresses on the same single HW network card.

Your host and its HW network interface might be in `--subnet=192.168.1.0/24`. /24 ensures proper on-link determination in order to directly reach other IP addresses (hosts and MACVLANs) within the same subnet.

So far, you might have hosts in the range of, say, 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.31.

Now you want to allocate MACVLAN IP addresses in this subnet in order to talk to the existing hosts or other MACVLANs. But you don't want to trample on the existing host-assigned IP addresses.

So you use just a small subrange of your /24 network to allocate IP addresses from for your virtual MACVLANs. For instance, `--ip-range=192.168.1.192/26`.

If you would just set subnet==ip-range then you would always need an IP router (gateway) to reach anyone outside that range; and depending on your setup the other hosts might not be able to talk back as they assume a different subnet (size).